# How to update a row when certain rows in another table are updated?

Tags: postgresql, concurrency

We have two tables, orders and order_products,

each order can have many order_products (thus, one to many relation)

```sql
CREATE TABLE orders (id UUID PK, status VARCHAR)
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE order_products (id UUID PK, order_id UUID FK, status VARCHAR)
```

order_products are processed in parallel using a message broker.

How do I set the status of order to COMPLETED when all order_products have been COMPLETED ?

Ideally, I don't want to get an exclusive lock on order because then order_products can not be processed in parallel.

**Possible solution:**

Defining `completed_order_products` on `orders` table and whenever an `order_product` gets completed, increment the value of `completed_order_products` by 1, also, setting up a trigger on `orders` so after each update, it would check whether `completed_order_products` is equal to total `order_products` of that order or not.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find that often the best/easiest way to accomplish a task is to just not do it. That seems to be the case here. Your task is making sure you indicate an order is complete only when each order_product status is complete.  You can accomplish this without trying to update the order when when status of an order_product is updated. Instead create a VIEW that determines the status of the overall `orders` from the individual `order_products`. The following is one such method.  
First create an [ENUM](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/datatype-enum.html) with the status values. Now enums have an interesting ordering:

> The ordering of the values in an enum type is the order in which the values were listed when the type was created. All standard comparison operators and related aggregate functions are supported for enums.

Second, create a view for the order which selects the minimum value from the enum. Since you did not specify the status values other than complete, I'll create a sample set. (see [demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=89bad0ee1a68832cc2fafc3c11689977))

```
create type order_status_t as enum (
    'pending',
    'in progress',
    'complete'); 

-- view for order status:
create view order_status as  
       ( select order_id 
              , min(status) status  
           from order_products
          group by order_id
       );    

-- get each order status:      
select * 
  from order_status 
  order by order_id;
```

With minimal change this could accomplished with a lookup table for status values and their relative sequence instead of an enmu.

---

**REVISED**  
As I indicated I think you missed the point. The status on `order` does not exist on its own, but derived from the combination of status values and thus **not stored**; as such there is no CDC needed. However you can keep a **at this moment** order status column *if absolutely needed* however complexity grows considerable. The following is one way, about as short as I can devise at the moment. It requires the addition of:

1. Trigger and trigger function for updating the `order` status on every DML operation on `order_products'.
2. A trigger and trigger function for inserting the CDC on every DML on the `orders` table.
3. A stand-alone function to derive the `order` status from the `order_product` status values. This replaces the VIEW.
4. The addition of a *no products* status value ENUM type  (of a higher sequence than Complete).

See code and some tests [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=d78a57938f2bf07e05bd646d9bcb6e84). This is a very **minimalist** example of what is needed.  You are, as always do when you store derivable values, potentially facing considerable maintenance issues and performance issues.

Comment: Thank you for the very well-written and nicely explained answer. Correct me if I'm wrong but what you are suggesting, solves the problem when we are selecting the order ourselves right? I have CDC in place, How do I trigger my CDC (update the order) in the event a VIEW has all of its rows as COMPLETED?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response, I was away for a bit. I think you missed the point. The status of the `order` is a derived value and is **not stored**.  Take a look at the demo. The `order` table does not contain a column for status, so there is nothing to update in the it.  In particular see order #3 which is *updated* in the demo to a status completed. Do not have the time at the moment but I will think about an alternative this evening.

Comment: It really is unbelievable you putting this much time and effort into my question, just wanted to let you know that I am really appreciative. I completely understood the concept of setting up a view to check current status of order by getting corresponding order_product statuses, but since I need for a change to happen in order to trigger my CDC, I was thinking of creating a trigger on order_products, which will update order.status IF all order_products matching order.id are COMPLETED, I think that really solves my issue (since the operation is non blocking), what do you think?

Comment: I guess that would work if incomplete.  What you do need however is handle the situations where the status would go from `Complete` to `not Complete`.